# How to get http request and query string params in the controller

Tags: java, playframework

I'm new in the play framework. I'm using play 2.8.x framework and I need to get from the controller session object and params from request. But I don't realize how to do that.
My `routes` file looks like the following:

```
POST /api/verifyToken/:token        controllers.UserController.verifyToken(token: String, request: Request)
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
public class UserController extends Controller {
    public Result verifyToken(String token, Http.Request request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and when I try to send a request to the server I had had an error but if I remove `token` parameter all is working fine. 
How can I pass the request and params to the controller?

Comment: How does you request look like? What is the error you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler is given the `Http.Request` when it is called:

```
java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]> queryParams = request.queryString();
```

for the session:

```
Http.Session session = request.session();
```